# How to get json data into apex salesforce?

Tags: json, apex

I have a json like this, which i am getting in the response from http call

```
{
  "offset": 0,
  "limit": 50,
  "objects": [
    {
      "id": "59118fb6e4b0168ec4b56692",
      "modifiedDate": 1494323126886,
      "requestedIds": null,
      "mergedIds": [],
      "properties": {
        "name": [
          {
            "value": "Abhimanyu",
            "metadata": {}
          }
        ],
        "company": [],
        "title": [],
        "email": [
          {
            "value": "absinghrathore127@gmail.com",
            "metadata": {}
          }
        ]
      },
      "state": "ACTIVE"
    },
    {
      "id": "590d5813e4b03a8336fa1642",
      "modifiedDate": 1494046739619,
      "requestedIds": null,
      "mergedIds": [],
      "properties": {
        "name": [
          {
            "value": "Tim Archer",
            "metadata": {}
          }
        ],
        "company": [],
        "title": [],
        "email": [
          {
            "value": "tim@avocado.com",
            "metadata": {}
          }
        ]
      },
      "state": "ACTIVE"
    }
  ],
  "size": 2
}
```

and i am able to get objects from json via this following code :

```
 String s = res.getBody();
    Map<String,Object> jsonMap = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(s);
    String jsonSubset = JSON.serialize(jsonMap.get('objects'));
```

What i need is the value of name and email in some variable.
Please help me out in this!!

Answer (score 0):

This is going to be a tedious task but once you've classified your all data into appropriate `Wrapper` classes then it's fairly simple and easy to maintain.

First thing is to define your `MainWrapper` class. This will contain all the at it's own level. If it has any Object as key-pair then we need to make sure to include it as a `List<>`. So This is how your `MainWrapper` should be:

```
public class MainWrapper {
    Integer offset;  // Singleton variable
    Integer limits;  // Singleton variable
    List<ObjectsWrapper> objects;  // Collection variable since it starts with [],
    Integer size;  // Singleton variable
}
```

Since you've array of `objects` in JSON that's why I've included it as a `List` in `MainWrapper`. Now it's time to define `ObjectsWrapper`. Below is wrapper defined for the same.

```
public class ObjectsWrapper {
    String id;
    String modifieddate;
    String requestedIds;
    PropertyWrapper properties;
}
```

Since there is only on `properties` associated with `objects` that's why it's a non-collection type. Below is representation of `properties`.

```
public class PropertyWrapper {
    List<NameWrapper> name;
    List<String> company;
    List<String> title;
    List<EmailWrapper> email;
    String state;
}

public class NameWrapper {
    String name;
    String metadata;
}
```

I guess now you've a fair idea of how to organize data of JSON into various wrapper class. Once you're done with this, simply deserialize the JSON into `MainWrapper` class and access it.
For example:

```
MainWrapper mainJSONWrapper = (MainWrapper) JSON.deserialize(JSON,MainWrapper.class);
List<ObjectsWrapper> objectsLst = mainJSONWrapper.objects;
for(ObjectsWrapper obj:objectsLst) {
    List<NameWrapper> lstNameWrapper = obj.properties;
    for(NameWrapper nameObj:NameWrapper) {
        System.debug('Name:'+nameObj.name);
        System.debug('metadata:'+nameObj.metadata);
    }
}
```

Above code is not tested but yes, it will give idea how you should deserialize JSON in appropriate manner.

Also go through this answer..[How to deserialize a JSON String to Apex](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/57459/how-to-deserialize-a-json-string-to-apex)

Comment: Hey @Rohit Mourya, Thanks for the answer. I have applied your code. but getting this error .System.JSONException: Expected List<PropertyWrapper> but found {

Comment: Try replacing `PropertyWrapper properties;` with `List<PropertyWrapper> properties;`.

Comment: and the code is stucking on the 1st line itself i.e. MainWrapper mainJSONWrapper = (MainWrapper) JSON.deserialize(JSON,MainWrapper.class);

Comment: MainWrapper mainJSONWrapper = (MainWrapper) JSON.deserializeUntyped(s);
        List<ObjectsWrapper> objectsLst = mainJSONWrapper.objects;
        for(ObjectsWrapper obj:objectsLst) {
            List<PropertyWrapper> lstPropertyWrapper = obj.properties;
           for(PropertyWrapper propertyWrapper:lstPropertyWrapper) {
                List<NameWrapper> nameWrapper =propertyWrapper.name;
                for(NameWrapper nameObj:nameWrapper) {
                    System.debug('Name:'+nameObj.name);
                }
            }
        }

Comment: The above code i have written as suggested by you @Rohit Mourya

Comment: @abhimanyusinghrathore That was just for reference. I mentioned earlier as well. However the motive was to give you an idea of how to map your JSON with wrapper classes. First try to map simple JSON with single wrapper class and then go on.. doing it.